# Prove $(p \lor r) \to (\lnot r \to p)$

Tags: logic

Prove 
$(p \lor r) \to (\lnot r \to p)$ is a tautology.

I have tried to prove that by using truth table, but is there any another way to prove it?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $a \rightarrow b \equiv b \lor \lnot a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to prove it it a tautology is to simply 'prove' the statement is true under no new given assumptions.

$$\begin{align} p\lor r &\implies r\lor p\\
&\implies \neg r \to p\end{align}$$

You can also assume it is false and reach a contradiction.

Suppose the statement is false. Then $p\lor r$ is true, but $\neg r \to p$ is false. Since $p\lor r$ is true, then $p$ is true or $r$ is true.

If $p$ is true, then clearly $\neg r\to p$ is true, contradiction.
If $r$ is true, then $\neg r$ is false and so $\neg r\to p$ is true, contradiction.

Therefore $\neg r\to p$ is true and hence $p\lor r\to (\neg r\to p)$.

Comment: what is this mean? →¬r→p

Comment: @MathR It means nothing, it was a typo. You should read $\implies$ as whatever is after $\implies$ is a logical consequence of whatever is before $\implies$.

Comment: Needs a "thumb's up"! +1

Comment: @amWhy Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

> The proof can be made entirely mechanical using the identity $(a\to b)=(\lnot a\lor b)$ for every $a$ and $b$ and the fact that $a\to a$ is a tautology for every $a$.

Let $q=(p \lor r)$, $s=(\lnot r \to p)$ and $t=q\to s$.

Then $s=(r\lor p)$ hence $t=(p \lor r)\to(r\lor p)$, which is a tautology since $(p \lor r)=(r\lor p)$.

Comment: I simply it to $(p \lor r) \to (r \lor p)$, and then by the conditional truth table, TT->T, FF->T, so it's tautology, am I right?

Comment: As @Daniel explained in a comment.

Comment: I am not sure that "the conditional truth table, TT->T, FF->T" is relevant at all but yes, this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assume 'p' false.  So, (p $\lor$ r)=r (where the valuation of sentences comes as assumed).

Thus, [(p∨r)→(¬r→p)]=[r→(¬r→p)].  '[r→(¬r→p)]' qualifies as a tautology, so [(p∨r)→(¬r→p)] holds as true when 'p' is false.

Assume 'p' true.  Thus, '(¬r→p)' qualifies as true, and so does '[(p∨r)→(¬r→p)]'.

By the principle of bivalence, it follows that '[(p∨r)→(¬r→p)]' qualifies as a tautology.